# How to change the color of selected row and unselected row in UITableview?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uitableview

I want to change the color of selected row and unselected row in uitableview when user select a particular row from it.

Tell me the sample code or any link for it.
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
cell.contentView.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:0 green:0 blue:0 alpha:0.25];
```

By changing the value of red, green, blue, you can change the color of the cell when selected.

Answer (score 1):

In the `cellForRowAtIndexpath` method,

set `backgroundView`  and `selectedBackgroundView` property of [UITableViewCell](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UITableViewCell_Class/Reference/Reference.html).

You just create a new UIView object with required background color and assign that view to the property.

```
UIView *normalView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:cell.bounds];
normalView.backgroundColor = [UIColor blueColor];
cell.backgroundView = normalView;
[normalView release];
```

Similarly for `selectedBackgroundView`.

Then finally set

```
[cell.textLabel setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];
```